# How to render All layers in my Compositor at once

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have a node grid that renders and adds 10 different layers together. I have added a composition node in the end of the node grid. Though when i Render (F12) it seems like only one of the layers in the composition is rerendered and the other nodes are just applied without rerendering. How can I make all nodes rerender when hitting Render(F12)?

Sorry if my question is unclear, I am a Blender beginner so find it hard to explain my problem.

Any help appreciated! Thanks! :)

[image]

Currently I have to press each "green-render-button" (marked in image) to finally get the complete result. I would like to be able to just press Render (marked in orange) and have them all rendered into final image.

Obviously there is something I don't understand because I can't make sense out of it...

[image: Here are the layer list render settings]

Comment: Could you upload a .blend file that showcases the issue? What are you trying to achieve? If you can't upload a .blend file, try attaching screenshots to your answer, you can upload the .blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: In addition to the nodes, please also give us a picture of your render layers setup in the properties window.

Comment: I have now tried adding more relevant information. I can add more information if needed. I can not upload the blender file though, because my work is for school and uploading it can cause troubles...

Comment: One more important thing to show is setup of the [render layers settings](https://www.blender.org/manual/pt/render/post_process/layers.html) located in the [Properties Editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/pt/editors/properties_editor.html). It could happen that you checked only one layer to be re-rendered (the selected one); it's a small icon to the right from the render layers list.

Comment: @MrZak added an image of the Render layer list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You selected *Only render the active layer* option in the [Render layers](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html) list.

[image: screenshot of only active render layer will be rendered]

With this option only currently selected render layer (active one) will be rendered while others won't be; thus while compositing you'll see new results only on this active render layer.
From manual:

> Using Render Layers can save you from having to re-render your entire image each time you change something, allowing you to instead re-render only the layer(s) that you need.

Deactivate this option and all the Render layers will be rendered again when you press <kbd>F12</kbd> (or with any other way).

Comment: Great you solved my issue! Thanks! All buttons in Blender can be quite overwhelming and confusing for a noob like me ;)